# Ruby .inject() -- need help understanding this code

Tags: ruby

This code takes an array and returns only unique values.

**Why is the second 'keep' required for this code to work??**
Without it, I get this error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass

```
class Array
  def my_uniq_inject
    self.inject([]) do |keep, num|
      keep << num unless keep.include?(num)
      keep  # why is this required?
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: As a sidenote: this duplicates behavior that is already available from the standard library: `Array#uniq!`

Answer (score 5):

You may be confused because normally `arr << x` returns `arr`, so you would think you're fine.

It's the `unless` part that can screw things up here. If the last element in the array is not unique (i.e., it's already appeared earlier in the array) then the `unless` clause will cause the expression to evaluate to `nil`.

See for yourself:

```
arr = []
arr << 1              # [1]
arr << 2 unless false # [1, 2]
arr << 3 unless true  # nil
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `inject`/`reduce` takes return value of your block and replaces memo/accumulator with it.

You could use `each_with_object` which doesn't replace the memo

```
self.each_with_object([]) do |num, keep|
  keep << num unless keep.include?(num)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The second `keep` is for to reinitialize the `keep` here `do |keep,num|`,after the first pass. See the doc [`enum#inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) is saying at the second para last line **At the end of the iteration, the final value of memo is the return value for the method.**

Answer (score 1):

You need `keep` at the end of the block, because the result of the block is used as the accumulator for the next iteration of `inject`.

Without that `keep`, the first line in your block will sometimes return `keep` but sometimes return `nil` (when the conditional is not met, specifically).

Answer (score 0):

The second `keep` is required because of your condition in the previous line. If `keep.include?(num)` evaluates to false, `nil` will be returned to the `inject` accumulator. That's not really what you want to happen: you basically want that iteration to be skipped, but retain the previous array. The second `keep` allows you to pass the array back to the accumulator.

Answer (score 0):

`inject` feeds the output of the block back in at each stage, and returns the output of the block at the end.

When you are using `inject` to aggregate data, you need to return the object that is receiving the combined data at the end the block, otherwise on the next iteration the block variable will end up pointing at something else, causing odd effects - usually an error.

You don't have to use `inject` purely for aggregation though, and could in theory switch objects around if it suited your purpose. In practice I think this is a rare use of `inject`